# Use local full path with $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a possibility to use (for an offline website) a absolute path, going via c:\?
at the moment i'm using `$.get('sps_com/sendNP01.asp'...`

but i need to use `$.get('c://temp_sps/sps_com/sendNP01.asp'`

Comment: No, that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: And even if you could do it, it won't run the `.asp` script. Scripts are only run when accessed through a webserver. Accessing local files just gets the contents.

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as $.get works only with Http protocol and you are trying to use a file. An other alternative is to use offline(localhost) is just install IIS server as you are using asp file. After that you will able to call that file using http protocol.